# how to update column in a oracle table and commit after each record update by using python and cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

Here I want to update record in batch.like my program should update initial 50k record as null and commit and each record update.The again it should pick the next 50k record and do the same.

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> con = cx_Oracle.connect('ods/odss@dwdb3.test.com/DWdb3')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> statement = ('UPDATE dumy_uvcredit set CCNUMBEREXT=null')
>>> cur.execute(statement)
>>> con.commit()
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to do it from python and run a batch update ? It looks like a one time update operation. why not simply run the statement once? Or you may take a look at ctas technique for such bulk updates https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: Here We have huge data in tables and when we run update statement on any column at one go by firing sql statement then it is creating huge log file and it is creating problem in existing job in production.

Comment: so I was thinking to do it by python and just giving the threshold value of 50k for commit.Means the code will execute the statement and commit only after 50k.Here we dont have any identifier and only 3 column needs to be updated from the table.All values no filter.

Comment: Is there some date column that you can use to update say a week at a time or a day at a time? You could commit after each update.

Comment: What *huge log file*? What *problem in existing job in production*? If it's less than a million or two rows I'd just do the update in one shot, maybe using parallel DML to speed it up. If your database can't update a million rows in one go then you probably need a better laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible for you to use the following approach

```
alter table dumy_uvcredit add  new_CCNUMBEREXT <the datatype of CCNUMBEREXT>;
alter table dumy_uvcredit rename column CCNUMBEREXT to old_CCNUMBEREXT;
alter table dumy_uvcredit rename column new_CCNUMBEREXT to CCNUMBEREXT;
alter table dumy_uvcredit SET UNUSED (old_CCNUMBEREXT);
```

the dbms_redefinition package could be used to drop unused columns without interfering with ongoing operations

Comment: i want  python script to update column value to null for all records.also the update will be with commit for record # >50000.

Comment: i understand, - you will achieve the same end result using the approach I sketched for you - and I guess my suggestion would be the one recommended by Oracle - have a look at this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:623063677753

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend DDL for something that should be done within a transaction. This approach will lock the whole table, will invalidate existing code, and will issue an implicit commit both before and after each step, so a failure will not result in an automatic rollback.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - your right about the locking - but it will lock the table for less than one second. When you mention existing code - do you know that they have existing code (PL/SQL) that will be invalidated? Could it be possible for them to get a service window for doing that. They are not saying anything about context - but for me it seems to be related to cleaning up bad data.